# High CPU over a period of time and the top processes in that period

Tags: powershell, wmi

So far I have done a Powershell script that polls servers for their average CPU usage, memory usage, and hdd usage using WMI and output reports in HTML.

Does WMI have a mechanism that allows me to get the datetimes when the CPU usage has been over x% for over x minutes and list the top processes at the time.

Does WMI allow me to do this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered with Windows Performance Monitor a while back and it looked like a good server performance visualization solution. It allows for alerts to be sent for various conditions (ex. performance counter exceeds threshold). If you are interested in that, here is a link to it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154(v=ws.11).aspx

For using WMI to monitor server performance check out this blog post: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kevinholman/2008/07/02/collecting-and-monitoring-information-from-wmi-as-performance-data/

Note: To display the WMI Tester, goto `Start > Run` then type `wbemtest.exe`.